# Fancybox doesn't zoom in, it just shows exactly the same size of the picture.

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm having trouble with these theme Velo that uses Fancybox, but I can't seem to make the image zoom in. Help?

http://writtenwordcalligraphy.website/product/box-of-glue-gun-sealing-wax/

Comment: I was able to change the minimum width and minimum height to force it to zoom, but it's still calling the image that is smaller. I need to call the image that is larger. How do I make it do that?  it calls this image instead: http://writtenwordcalligraphy.website/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Seals-7-570x444.jpg

Comment: Okay, Can you post your code? Or fiddle would be great idea?